# parted: invalid token

Tags: partition, parted

I am teaching myself parted. In the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#Running-Parted) it reads:

> Parted has two modes: command line and interactive. Parted should always be started with:
>
> ```
> # parted device
> ```
>
> [...] In command line mode, this is followed by one or more commands. For example:
>
> ```
> # parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart P1 ext3 1MiB 8MiB
> ```
>
> [...] In interactive mode, commands are entered one at a time at a prompt, and modify the disk immediately.

When I run the former line it seems instead that parted goes interactive waiting for user input and raises the error:

```
parted: invalid token: mkpart
```

Am I missing something or is there a bug in the documentation?

PS: The error does not show with `-s` switch.

Answer (score 4):

## It is a bug in the documentation.

When using the command line you cannot leave the "Partition name" portion blank.

Also, the "parted: invalid token: mkpart" is because of the

> Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/xvdf will be destroyed and
> all data on this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
>
> Yes/No?

Since `mkpart` is not Yes or No you get the invalid token error message.

Fix:  Use the `-s` or `--script` option.

```
sudo parted -s /dev/xvdf mklabel gpt mkpart MyPartName 'ext2' '0%' '100%' print all
```